# Android Auto/Automotive, is it possible to integrate in one app multiple categories?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-auto, android-automotive

The main thing which i don't understand is about app categories. Is it possible to use in one application multiple categories ?
I must to develop app where i will implement map with some routes and beside that must be media service which will trigger on some location and launch media file or multiple media files, how to implement that for car ?